# Export Multi-Dimensional Array Data into Excel in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel, export-to-excel

When Trying to export multi dimensional array into excel using php I got only empty excel file , i am new to work with phpExcel
I know that this kind of questions were already asked and answered but I am tired by analyse all the answers ,
I need to know what is the problem  in my code, how will clear it to get expected output.

I need output as in the Image

[image: I want to get excel output as]

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once('/var/www/html/aws/arun/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');


    $sheet = array();

    $array1 = array("Body","ID","Group");
    array_push($sheet,$array1);
    $array2 = array("Mesaage 1" , "10", "11");
    array_push($sheet,$array2);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($sheet);
    echo '</pre>';



    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Excel Export');

    foreach($sheet as $row => $val){
    foreach($val as $column => $value){
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $value);
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below you can export the file to a csv if that works for you?

```
$sheet = array();

$array1 = array("Body","ID","Group");
array_push($sheet,$array1);
$array2 = array("Mesaage 1" , "10", "11");
array_push($sheet,$array2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sheet);
echo '</pre>';

//open file ready to write to
//'c+' opens the file or creates if it doesn't already exist
$fo = fopen('YOURFILEPATHHERE','c+');

//loop through array
foreach ($sheet as $lines) {
//push array values to line in the csv file
fputcsv($fo,$lines);
}

//close file
fclose($fo);
```

This outputs a csv that meets your requirements.

Make sure you have permission to write into the location you specify at YOURFILEPATHHERE.

Find out more information about fputcsv and fopen visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`$row` needs to start from `1` if you're using `setCellValueByColumnAndRow()`, because MS Excel worksheet rows start from 1 (note that Excel never has cell `A0`)

But you might find using the Worksheet's fromArray() method is easier

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and change little bit according to your requirement

```
$header = array("Body","ID","Group");
    $array2 = array("Mesaage 1" , "10", "11");


    $list = array ($header);

    $filename = "mmyexcel.xls";


    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Excel Export');

    $list[] = $array2;

    $sheet->fromArray($list);


    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```